High error rate in load testing ASP.NET Core
I have created a simple application in ASP.NET Core 8, which returns a plain String "Hello World" using a basic controller. My code looks as follows:
    public interface Interface
    {
        string GetMessage();
    }

    public class Class : Interface
    {
        public string GetMessage()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        Interface interface;

        public ValuesController(Interface @interface)
        {
            interface = @interface;
        }


        [HttpGet("/getHelloWorld")]
        public IActionResult getHelloWorld()
        {
            var response = interface.GetMessage();
            return Ok(response);
        }
    }

I have launched the application and checked if it works, and then I wanted to perform some load testing. When I set up 4000 users, I received 80% errors, each showing "Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connect to localhost:7271 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect". What could be the issue? For example, when I wrote an identical application in Spring Boot, I received only 7% errors "Connection refused: connect".
I tried to increase MaxConcurrentConnections in Kestrel or set AllowSynchronousIO = true, but it didn't help.

I can try to help diagnose this issue, but with the data you provided I can only guess and there's no guessing in performance measuring. Please provide minimal repro - you've missed to much code that can have great impact on performance, like e.g. middleware. Only tip that I can give having what you posted is that AllowSynchronousIO = true when you want to serve many clients concurrently is definitely bad - request needs a thread to be processed and with blocking IO you have a lot of threads waiting for IO when they could have serve other requests in the meantime.

Another tip is - skip MVC and use minimal API instead. You have to pay a price for all the MVC machinery and it is significant.

you should test again with async methods (all the way through) on the backend.  Return Task...  (I'd also rename those classes/interfaces with something more unique... might have a reserved word in there...)

Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

I will recommend publishing the application and hosting it locally on IIS. You can then configure IIS settings. By default, it has no real limits on concurrent connections and bandwidth (they are there, but the numbers are likely way more than enough). I would assume the bottleneck to be the CPU and memory used by the application pool. Open application pool's advanced settings and configure CPU settings based on your CPU. You can experiment with worker count too. Also perhaps compare ".NET CLR" vs. "no managed code". Make sure you dont have rate limiting middleware.

a common approach is to set the number of worker processes to the number of logical cores available. for example, i5-4460 has 4 physical cores and 4 logical cores (AKA threads, see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/80817/intel-core-i54460-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz/specifications.html), so the optimal worker count would be 4 (assuming there are no other apps being hosted on the server). This alone would pretty much quadruple the performance. note that there are things to keep in mind when doing this, such as managing distributed sessions, or using redis, etc.

@EmreBener Indeed, deploying the application on IIS resulted in fewer errors, as with the same number of users, there are approximately 7% errors. Thanks for your help.

@browsermator The link you've posted is for ASP.NET MVC 4, check out ASP.NET Core performance best practices  for up-to-date info, especially Avoid blocking calls section

@망명학살자 You can verify statements mentioned by me earlier using dotnet counters CLI tool, especially take a look at thread pool counters. Bear in mind hosting in IIS hides the real problem under the rug. If you're willing to accept that - it's fine, just be aware of that.
